# Twitter auth using artdarek/oauth-4-laravel

Tags: laravel, twitter

I trying to retreive Twitter oauth_token using Twitter API method oauth/request_token. 
How can I send POST request using artdarek wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out with this question.

First step - method to get authorization URL

```
public function getTwitterToken()
{
    $tw = OAuth::consumer('Twitter');
    $reqToken = $tw->requestRequestToken();
    $url = $tw->getAuthorizationUri(array('oauth_token' => $reqToken->getRequestToken()));
    echo $url;
}
```

Next step - auth in twitter and retrieve oauth_token and oauth_verifier. 
Example [here](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel).